# Need to make a tool that converts xml to xsd?

Tags: xml, xsd

I want to write a tool in java that converts 
1. xml to xsd
2. and from xsd to owl.

Here is a sample xml that should be the input. can someone give the steps to write such a tool ?

```
<note>
<to> Tove</to>
<from>Jani</from>
<heading>Reminder</heading>
<body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
</note>
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at this to XML -> XSD using JAXB library

http://wangxiangblog.blogspot.fr/2011/05/how-to-convert-xsd-to-xml-or-vice-versa.html

And with some research about JAXB, it'will be possible to convert xsd to owl i think